# Can a grounded spherical shell have a charge?

Tags: electrostatics, charge, conductors

Can a grounded spherical shell lying inside another bigger non-grounded shell have charge on it? If yes then why? Won't the charge on the grounded conductor flow to the ground?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the two spheres to be conducting, with the inner sphere  of radius $a$ and the outer of radius $b$. If the outer sphere carries a charge $Q$, then the inner will have a charge $-\dfrac{a}{b}Q$.

In fact, the charge on the outer one will create a potential $V=\dfrac{kQ}{b}$ on its surface and inside. Therefore, to keep its zero potential, the inner sphere has to get a charge equal to $-\dfrac{a}{b}Q$ which will create a potential $-V$ on it, and the latter adds up with the first potential to zero. I think this charge is carried up to the inner sphere by the field of stray capacitance between the outer sphere and earth.